# Loop over html table and get names of checked checkboxes (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table with a checkbox in each row.

I want to loop over the table and see if there are any checkboxes that are checked.
The following does not work:

```
$(document).on("click", "#Button2", function(event)
{
        $('#mytable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function()
        {
                console.log($(this).text());
        });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dHZS9/696/

In the above fiddle Initially Select some checkboxes (For example A , B , H)

On click of a button how to get names for which checkbox is selected (For Example A, B, H) in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The texts do not belong to the `input` elements you loop over, but to their parent elements (labels), so replace your `console.log` by this:

```
console.log($(this).parent().text());
```

Alternatively, you can change the selector and select the labels that have a checked checkbox as child:

```
$('#mytable').find('label:has(input[type="checkbox"]:checked)').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**The text is not within the input check**, for that reason the `$(this).text()` does not work.

You need to go to your parent of your checkout input in this case to your label tag and now execute the `.text()` function to get the text.

Change your line like this:

```
console.log($(this).parent().text());
```

Regards!